# How to click a button with no name

Tags: html, vbscript, form-submit

I'm trying to click a button with VBScript using the following code:

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
IE.Navigate "google.com" 
IE.Visible = True 
Wscript.Sleep 2000 
IE.Document.All.Item("uss").Value = "username" 
IE.Document.All.Item("pass").Value = "pass" 
IE.Document.All.Item("character").Value = "character"
IE.Document.All("").Click()
```

How could I click a button that has no name?

Here's the `submit` button I'm trying to select:

```
<td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" value="Submit Now!"></td>
```

Observe that the button has no name. If I try to use the submit function, the scipt doesn't work or the webpage doesn't respond. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have not a piece of choice in this case, so grab by tag name.

```
For Each btn In IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    If btn.type = "submit" Then btn.Click()
Next
```